# How to randomly access data from a Java Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I get an Iterator back from a class and I would like to get the xth element of that iterator.  I know I could load it into an ArrayList in a loop or check a counter, but that seems inefficient/ugly.  What is the best way to do this?

I thought something like,

```
List al = new ArrayList(myIterator);
  myval = al.get(6);
```

But that constructor is undefined.  thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you've named the only approaches.  You're going to end up needing a `for` loop to iterate to the appropriate position.

A few utility libraries have shortcuts to [load an `Iterator`'s contents into an `ArrayList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28java.util.Iterator%29), or to [get the `n`th element of an `Iterator`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#get%28java.util.Iterator,%20int%29), but there's nothing built into the JDK.

Answer (score 9):

The definition of an `Iterator` does not allow arbitrary indexing to a position.  That's just the way it's defined.  If you need that capability you will have to load the data into an indexable collection.

The point of the `Iterator` interface is to allow *sequential* access to a collection without knowing anything about its size.  Iterators can be forward-only or bi-directional (`ListIterator`).  It's just one specific model for accessing elements of a collection.  One advantage is that it implies nothing about the collection size, which could be much too large to fit completely into memory.  By allowing only sequential access, the implementation is free to keep only part of the collection in memory at any given moment.

If you need to load the iterator contents into a list you need to do it yourself with a loop.

Comment: Did you read the OP's code?  The OP is aware of all this.  They're asking if they should load the `Iterator`'s contents into an `ArrayList` in a loop, or use a counter to iterate to the `n`th element of the iterator.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Jim's answer suggests that loading an iterable into a collection, such as an array list, is the most efficient way to do what the OP is trying to.

Comment: The OP indicates they know that an `Iterator` only allows sequential access, but they're asking if there's a more compact, readable way to do that or to otherwise get the `n`th element.

Comment: I was trying to explain the underlying reasons why indexing an iterator is not valid.  I edited my answer to be more explicit about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround i have this method in my Utilities class

```
     /**
     * Retrieve the n position object of iterator 
     * @param iterator
     * @param position
     * @return Object at position
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static Object iterateTo(Iterator iterator, int position) throws Exception{
        
        if(iterator == null){
            throw new Exception("iterator == null");
        }

        if(position < 0){
            throw new Exception("position < 0");
        }
        
        while(iterator.hasNext() && position > 0){
            position--;
            iterator.next();
        }
        
        if(position != 0){
            throw new Exception("position out of limit");
        }
        
        return iterator.next();
        
    }
```

so instead of this

```
{
List al = new ArrayList(myIterator);
  myval = al.get(6);
}
```

you will have to

```
{
Object myVal = Utilities.iterateTo(myIterator, 6);
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain how this is random and how this reply to the question ?